# LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder ChannelHandler is removed, but still gets called on the next event

Tags: netty

I'm trying to process the following message:

```
CMD (string) FLAG (byte) CMD_OPT (string)
```

The strings are represented by a single leading byte containing the length, followed by a max of 255 bytes.  So for a specific example:

```
 EQ_REGISTER 0 flaux
```

there are 19 bytes.  In my pipeline, I start with a LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder and then once I confirm the value of the first string, I try to remove the first decoder.  The problem is, the decoder gets called again on the FLAG byte, and my logic is off.

Here's my pipeline:

```
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast("commandDecoder", new CerbStringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("commandHandler", new EventQueueCmdServerHandler());
```

CerbStringDecoder is this:

```
   class CerbStringDecoder extends LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder {
    public CerbStringDecoder() {
        super(255, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    }


    protected Object decode(
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
        ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) super.decode(ctx, channel, buffer);

        if (buf == null)
            return null;

        return buf.toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}


 public class EventQueueCmdServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {

        String command = (String) e.getMessage();

        if (EQ_REGISTER.equals(command)) {
            System.out.println("COMMAND: [" + command + "]");
            ctx.getPipeline().addLast("handler", new EventQueueRegisterHandler());
            ctx.getPipeline().remove("commandDecoder");

       ....
```

The EventQueueRegisterHandler expects to fetch the FLAG and the CMD_OPT, etc.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong, or if this is a bug / limitation in Netty?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "replace(..)" method to be sure that all buffered bytes are flushed out when removing it. See the javadocs for it [1].

[1] http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler)